# Subset dataframe to have not more than 5 records for each group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have a dataframe with a factor called diet. And say there are "herbivores", "carnivores", and "omnivores" as levels for the factor diet. And there are 3 herbivores, 6 carnivores, and 8 omnivores.

Basically I would like to filter this dataframe so that levels that have under 5 counts stay untouched and levels with more than 5 counts get filtered down to 5 (preferably randomly).

So, for example I would go from 3 herbivores, 6 carnivores, and 8 omnivores

```
    diet       factor2
1 herbivore     a
2 herbivore     a
3 herbivore     a
4 carnivore     a
5 carnivore     a
6 carnivore     a
7 carnivore     a
8 carnivore     a
9 carnivore     a
10 omnivore     a
11 omnivore     a
12 omnivore     a
13 omnivore     a
14 omnivore     a
15 omnivore     a
16 omnivore     a
17 omnivore     a
```

to 3 herbivores, 5 carnivores, and 5 omnivores.

```
        diet    factor2
1 herbivore     a
2 herbivore     a
3 herbivore     a
4 carnivore     a
5 carnivore     a
6 carnivore     a
7 carnivore     a
8 carnivore     a
9 omnivore     a
10 omnivore     a
11 omnivore     a
12 omnivore     a
13 omnivore     a
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `slice_sample`, which in dplyr 1.1.0 gained a `by` parameter:

```
set.seed(2023)
library(dplyr)
mtcars |>
  slice_sample(n = 5, by = carb) |>
  arrange(carb)                       # for easier visual review
```

Result

```
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Fiat 128          32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1 # 5 shown out of 7
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corolla    33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Fiat X1-9         27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 # 5 shown out of 10
Volvo 142E        21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
Dodge Challenger  15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
Porsche 914-2     26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 450SLC       15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 # 3 shown out of 3
Merc 450SE        16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL        17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 280C         17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 # 5 shown out of 10
Camaro Z28        13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Ferrari Dino      19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 # 1 shown out of 1
Maserati Bora     15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 # 1 shown out of 1
```

With prior (pryr?) dplyr:

```
mtcars |> 
  group_by(carb) |> 
  slice_sample(n = 5) |> 
  ungroup() |>
  arrange(carb)
```

Comment: I like this answer but I get this error: > mtcars |>
+   slice_sample(n = 5, by = carb) |>
+   arrange(carb)
Error in `slice_sample()`:
! `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• by = carb
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::arrange(slice_sample(mtcars, n = 5, by = carb), carb)
 3. dplyr:::slice_sample.data.frame(mtcars, n = 5, by = carb)

Comment: If I remove the "by" option and just ad the grou_by as you put for prior dplyr it works. But I have to do REPLACE=TRUE to make it work which I dont quite understand

Comment: Are you using dplyr 1.1.0? If an earlier version, that syntax won't work yet.

Comment: I don't think `REPLACE = TRUE` is what you want -- that will duplicate rows to pad up to n = 5; I would have expected you might get a warning but not an error if your groups are smaller than the requested n.

Comment: Yeah not sure why it isn't working. I am using 1.1.0 and I get the same error on my dataset and the mtcars dataset